# wdcalendar plugin run very slowly on IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I am using wdcalendar (http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/#calendar) with IE8.
In month view I have many events, and therefore the page loads very slowly. Sometimes I have to wait 20 seconds!

After analyzing the problem we noticed that the slow occurs on the html paint: IE8 runs slowly when jquery creates the html.

Does anyone have any idea how to make IE8 execute the code faster? What should I change in wdcalendar code in order to help IE8 execute faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried loading the page without the elements visible and then loading them in afterwards OR loading them in via jQuery after the page load?

Comment: What do you mean by "loading the page without the elements visible and then loading them in afterwards" and by "loading them in via jQuery after the page load"?
the code executed inside $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Comment: Sorry for the delay - If you rendered the month calenders in a hidden DIV (display:none;} then it's not repainting very often.  When it's finished working out the data, you can then show it, which will then cause a single repaint for the rendered code.  This is one possible way to approach a repaint issue, but you'd probably want to check it on another page to compare.  I think your approach is spot on, but if you use a hidden element for IE8, you *may* find it helps with the painting issue.  I'd be interested to know if it's noticeable.  Perhaps you can jsFiddle.net a sample?

Comment: It is a huge code to put on jsFiddle.. Do you suggect to set display:none to the primary table that holds all the structure and then, after all done, to show it??..

Comment: It's worth a check first.  I'd try that and compare.  If the performance isn't improved - a sample page that isn't data-sensitive would be cool to see to have a go with.

Comment: I did what you suggest but that didn't work. Anyway, I accept your answer because I believe there is no solution. IE8 is one of the worst browsers in the world up to now.